# Помогите разобраться с If

Tags: c#, if, move

If пропускает условие и сразу сносит спрайт. Я только начинаю учить. Никак не могу понять что тут не так.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Move : MonoBehaviour {
public bool b = true;

    void Start () {
        transform.position = new Vector2(0, 1);
    }


    void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(new Vector3(1, 0) * Time.deltaTime);

        if (transform.position.x > 3) ;
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ну а чему равно вот это `transform.position.x`?

Comment: может быть проблема в  if (transform.position.x > 3) ; в конце стоит (;)

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Я рилл тупой, поставил по привычке ; вот он и улетал сразу)

Comment: @RenatIsmailov, да без проблем)

Answer (score 2):

Я в c# не эксперт, но зачем тут

```
if (transform.position.x > 3) ;
```

точка с запятой?